# How to integrate OIDC Provider in Node jS

Tags: node.js, nodejs-server, oidc-provider, node-oidc-provider

I tried to Integrate OIDC Provider to Node JS and I have a Sample Code. So, I run this Sample code it's throwing an error(unrecognized route or not allowed method (GET on /api/v1/.well-known/openid-configuration)).The problem is Issuer(https://localhost:3000) this Issuer is working fine. but i will change this Issuer((https://localhost:3000/api/v1/)) it's not working How to fix this Issue and I facing another issue also when I implement oldc-provider in node js. They Routes are override how to fix this issue

**Sample.js**

```
const { Provider } = require('oidc-provider');
const configuration = {
  // ... see available options /docs
  clients: [{
    client_id: 'foo',
    client_secret: 'bar',
    redirect_uris: ['http://localhost:3000/api/v1/'],
    true_provider: "pcc"
    // + other client properties
  }],
};

const oidc = new Provider('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/', configuration);

// express/nodejs style application callback (req, res, next) for use with express apps, see /examples/express.js
oidc.callback()



// or just expose a server standalone, see /examples/standalone.js
const server = oidc.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('oidc-provider listening on port 3000, check http://localhost:3000/api/v1/.well-known/openid-configuration');
});
```

**Error**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Defining Issuer Identifier with a path component does not affect anything route-wise.

You have two options, either mount the provider to a path (see [docs](https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/v7.3.1/docs/README.md#mounting-oidc-provider)), or define the actual paths you want for each endpoint to be prefixed (see [docs](https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/v7.3.1/docs/README.md#routes)).

I think you're looking for a way to mount, so the first one.